# Filtering pandas with multiple conditions in a better way

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, filtering

I would like to assign names for the new column "SubtestName" based on the "SubtestID" column.

Currently my codes are as follows:

```
conditions = [(df4['subtestID'] == 325)|(df4['subtestID'] == 341)|(df4['subtestID'] == 1164)|(df4['subtestID'] == 1200),
              (df4['subtestID'] == 347)|(df4['subtestID'] == 357)|(df4['subtestID'] == 1308)|(df4['subtestID'] == 1330),
              (df4['subtestID'] == 328)|(df4['subtestID'] == 344)|(df4['subtestID'] == 1167)|(df4['subtestID'] == 1203)]

values = ["TestName1","TestName2","TestName3"]

df4['subTestName'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

I would like to rewrite my codes in a better way without repeating  "df4['subtestID']"  every time I want to assign a new ID. I am planning to assign another 30 subtestnames.

I tried using this way but it gave me an error.

```
df4['subtestID'] in (325,341,1164,1200)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Any other methods I can use to assign the names to the SubtestID?

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe, with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply us `isin()` as follows:

```
df4['subtestID'].isin([325,341,1164,1200])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing your code to:

```
s_id = df4['subtestID']
conditions = [s_id.isin(325,341,1164,1200),
              s_id.isin(347,357,1308,1330),
              s_id.isin(328,344,1167,1203)]

values = ["TestName1","TestName2","TestName3"]
df4['subTestName'] = np.select(conditions, values,'other name')
```

Comment: why not also cache `s_id.isin` then

Comment: Yes you can. I will delete the answer though I don't think it's adding value

Comment: i think it adds value but you didnt explain the value it adds

Comment: so yes its not adding value, code only answer